# Tiny URL that randomly opens a URL from list of URLs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, url, web

I'm trying to create a tiny URL that, when clicked, redirects to a randomly selected URL from a pre-determined list of URLs. I know I can achieve this server side with HTML and Javascript, but I want it to function purely from a tiny URL.

Basically how http://www.5050.degstu.com/ does it, but with no host restrictions or URL limit.

I'm pretty much lost with where to begin, and surprised that this doesn't already exist. Is it simply impossible to make for reasons beyond my understanding? I'm still relatively new to the dev world and might not fully grasp the complications involved with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "when clicked", does that mean the user can't type the URL directly into the browser's address bar? If you just want a link on a page that goes to a randomly chosen location that's easy enough, but the link element itself wouldn't have a URL.

Comment: @nnnnnn The user should be able to put the URL in their address bar, or click it as a hyperlink, thanks for clarification

Comment: What do you mean by "function purely from a tiny URL"?  You have basically a couple of options:  A) An HTTP redirect (e.g. HTTP 302 - Temporarily Moved).  B) A Refresh meta tag (HTML) or a refresh HTTP header.  C) Hosting an iframe with the random page.  D) Javascript refresh on the client side.  E) Acting as an HTTP proxy / load balancer and connecting to the other site yourself and serving back their content.

Comment: @PMV yeah sorry i'm still learning. I don't think I understand the TinyURL process properly, because I believed that it could shorten a group of URLs into 1 TinyURL, and then function in a way that randomly selects one of those URLs when clicked. But, I'm realizing that the function to perform the selection has to be stored somewhere. How does http://www.5050.degstu.com/ do this? Since it basically provides a link that randomly redirects to one of two possible URLs.. is it storing the URLs in a db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a script in the page that the TinyURL leads to:

```
var urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];

window.open(url, '_self');
```

It selects a random URL from a list of URLs, and then opens it in the same tab.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to achieve this without depending on a server side script that has to be in the pages HTML? I think that's what's happening here..

Comment: Do you have access to the page that the tiny url leads to?

Comment: I could create a landing page for this purpose, but I was hoping to find a work around and simply redirect using the TinyURL.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this because the tiny url must lead to a page, and the page would have to redirect.  But if the tiny url is supposed to be clicked on and not entered in the browser, then you could replace the tiny url with an <a> element and just modify the script so instead of saying "window.open", it says "document.getElementById('a-element-id').href = url;"  and just include that script in the page where your tiny url was.

Comment: Another solution is to replace the tiny url with a button that calls a JavaScript function which contains the code in my answer.

Comment: Calling a Javascript function which contains the code might be the solution i'm looking for, I will give that a try!

Comment: @Aleks If you don't want a button, you can still use an <a> element; just put "javascript:functionName()" for the href value

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at how 5050 does it if you're interested.

I just made a quick one and logged my connection with fiddler.  Here's what I got:

Request:

```
GET http://5050.degstu.com/v.php?l=qmf72tfeaya5y78 HTTP/1.1
Host: 5050.degstu.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

(and other headers that aren't really relevant)

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 03:39:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.vimeo.com
```

So they're using Option A from my comment - the server keeps some kind of database that matches the "qmf72tfeaya5y78" to the two URLs I gave (YouTube and Vimeo's homepages), and then the server sends back an HTTP 302 to tell my browser to redirect to one of those pages.

Comment: This is great, thanks for explaining, makes a lot more sense now!